# orderBy in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

JS:

```
$scope.termexamlist = {
    0:{
        0id:"1",
        1name:"Doe, John",
        2term1:"89"
    },
    1:{
        0id:"2",
        1name:"Aayt, Ray",
        2term1:"90"
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="t in termexamlist">
    <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in t">{{value}}</td>                 
</tr>
```

i got this `ng-repeat` code which generates list of students with their term exam grades, i want to sort it by `1name` but it didnt work i use to put  `<tr ng-repeat="t in termexamlist | orderBy:'1name' ">` but it didnt work. i tried different codings too but it didnt work either. Sorry im just a beginner in angularjs programming. Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Your definition of array is wrong:
`$scope.array = [{....}, {...}]` is array, `$scope.obj = {0: {...}, 1: {...}}` is object. You've mixed these two definitions :)

Comment: sorry my bad, it's not an array, it's an object.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have put identifiers when you declared your array

```
$scope.termexamlist = [
  {
    0id:"1",
    1name:"Doe, John",
    2term1:"89"
  },
  {
    0id:"2",
    1name:"Aayt, Ray",
    2term1:"90"
   }
];
```

This will be enough and enable you to iterate through it and ordering it.

Also, it's strange the way you prefix your variables, but that's none of my business

Comment: i need to put a prefix in my variable coz chrome sort the returned data in `json_encode`

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.termexamlist = [
      {
        0id:"1",
        1name:"Doe, John",
        2term1:"89"
      },
      {
        0id:"2",
        1name:"Aayt, Ray",
        2term1:"90"
      }
    ];
```

remove 0 and 1 in your data ,  it will work fine

Comment: sorry i can't delete the 0 and 1 coz the `$scope.termexamlist` is just a container of my `msg.data` which the data are already an object

Answer (score 0):

i got it now, i add underscore to the key of the object so it will look like this `$scope.termexamlist={0:{_0id:"1",_1name:"Doe, John",_2term1:"89"}}`. i retain the number coz chrome sort the returned data of `json_encode`